# RegEx to match comma separated numbers with optional decimal part

Tags: regex, actionscript

I've a regex that matches comma separated numbers with an optional two digit decimal part in a given multiline text.

```
/(?<=\s|^)\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?(?=\s|$)/m
```

It matches strings like 1, 12, 12.34, 12,345.67 etc successfully. How can I modify it to match a number with only the decimal part like `.23`?

EDIT: Just to clarify - I would like to modify the regex so that it matches `12`, `12.34` and `.34`

And I am looking for 'stand alone' valid numbers. i.e., number-strings whose boundaries are either white space or start/end of line/string.

Comment: Would be cool over here where commas are decimal delimiters and the dot is sometimes used as a thousands separator (though more commonly a space is) ^^

Comment: Oskar, that's just pure evil :D though great fun for a regex :D

Comment: @Oskar I was about to ask where in the hell are you living. But apparently there are lot of places where people use commas as decimal separator http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma I don't even wanna think about that part now. Even the normal notation is enough of a head ache to me :)

Comment: Check @Mez's answer. He covers both cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This:

```
\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?|\.\d\d
```

matches all of the following numbers:

```
1
12
.99
12.34 
12,345.67
999,999,999,999,999.99
```

If you want to **exclude** numbers like `123a` (street addresses for example), or `123.123` (numbers with more than 2 digits after the decimal point), try:

```
(?<=\s|^)(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?|\.\d\d)(?=\s|$)
```

A little demo (I guessed you're using PHP):

```
$text = "666a 1 fd 12 dfsa .99 fds 12.34 dfs 12,345.67 er 666.666 er 999,999,999,999,999.99";
$number_regex = "/(?<=\s|^)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d\d)?|\.\d\d)(?=\s|$)/";
if(preg_match_all($number_regex, $text, $matches)) {
  print_r($matches);
}
```

which will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 12
            [2] => .99
            [3] => 12.34
            [4] => 12,345.67
            [5] => 999,999,999,999,999.99
        )

)
```

Note that it ignores the strings `666a` and `666.666`

Comment: But that also matches `14` in `14.` or `145` in `145.2` and `1,344.12` in `1,344.123`

Comment: See my comment about word boundaries.

Comment: I'm using actionscript and apparently `.` is considered as word boundary and hence it still matches `14` in `asd 14. asd`. I'd already tried `\b` and found this issue, that's when I chose to use look around that I got from another SO thread. And btw, if you remember, I started this with the regex that you gave me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547574/regex-for-prices/1547585#1547585

Comment: Yes, you're right. Then use what you already posted yourself: replace the word boundaries by `(?<=\s|^)` and `(?=\s|$)`. Can your data contain strings like `123,123.12,456.45` (ie two successive numbers separated by a comma)? If so, could you then please adjust your original question and add all these corner cases?

Comment: Nope. I am looking for 'stand alone' valid numbers. Boundaries would be either white space or start/end of line/string. Will add this to the question. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem Amarghosh. See the edit, I think that covers it now.

Comment: Your updated regex that changed the structure from `(fixed.decimal)|(.decimal)` to `(fixed.decimal|.decimal)` is working fine. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Like that, there is no difference, but when doing: `^a|b$` it matches either an `a` at the beginning of the string, OR a `b` at the end. While `^(a|b)$` means: either an `a` or `b`.

Comment: Example: 
`a(b|c)|(d|e)f` would match ab or df, but not abf, wherase `a((b|c)|(d|e))f` would match abf, bit not df or ab

Comment: Eureka.. `(fix.dec)|(.dec)` fails on `14.` because it matches `^` followed by a `fix.dec` where dec is optional (which is `14`) followed by whatever (`.` here) or whatever followed by `.dec`. Thanks a ton, especially for that last two comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
/(?<=\s|^)(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?|\.(\d{2}))(?=\s|$)/m
```

Or taking into account some countries where . is used as a thousand seperator, and , is used as a decimal seperator

```
/(?<=\s|^)(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d{2})?|\.(\d{2})|,(\d{2}))(?=\s|$)/m
```

Insane Regex for Internationalisation

```
/((?<=\s)|(?<=^))(((\d{1,3})((,\d{3})|(\.\d{3}))*(((?<=(,\d{3}))(\.\d{2}))|((?<=(\.\d{3}))(,\d{2}))|((?<!((,\d{3})|(\.\d{3})))([\.,]\d{2}))))|([\.,]\d{2}))(?=\s|$)/m
```

Matches

```
14.23
14,23
114,114,114.23
114.114.114,23
```

Doesn't match

```
14.
114,114,114,23
114.114.144.23
,
.
<empty line>
```

Comment: `([0-9,\.])` matches a single character, to begin with. Even if you add a + it would matches , etc.

Comment: What is the difference between your 1st regex that encloses the whole thing in parenthesis like `(fixed.decimal|.decimal)` and `/(?<=\s|^)(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)|(\.\d{2})(?=\s|$)/` that puts them in separate parenthesis like `(fixed.decimal)|(.decimal)`? (other than the fact that second one matches `14` in `14.`)

Comment: To rephrase the last comment, why doesn't `(fixed.decimal)|(.decimal)` work? Is there any operator precedence that I am missing?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference..... I'd need to see the 2 alongside each other to spot the difference.

Comment: Ah, it depends on what you've got around it.

`a(fixed.decimal)|(.decimal)b` would not be the same as
`a((fixed.deciman)|(.decimal))b`

Comment: `/(?<=\s|^)(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)|(\.\d{2})(?=\s|$)/m` and the first regex in your answer.

Comment: In this case, no. As the look behinds/aheads are none matching. In a case where the look behind or ahead were not matching, then the brackets are there to limit the boundaries of the or.

Comment: But `/(?<=\s|^)(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?|\.\d{2})(?=\s|$)/m` and `/(?<=\s|^)(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)|(\.\d{2})(?=\s|$)/m` are giving me different results. 1st one works fine, but the second one matches `14` in `asd 14. asd`, `145` in `asd 145.2 asd` and `1,344.12` in `asd 1,344.123 asd`

Comment: Yeah. Thanks to your and @Bart's comments about `()`, now I understand the difference. I wish I could accept both answers :)

Comment: I understood the second one. But I don't dare even try the 'insane' one today. I've just started learning and I believe am not yet ready for such 'insanities' yet. Will come back later and try to break it down. Thanks again. Unfortunately I can accept only one answer, but I'm gonna upvote you somewhere else :)

Answer (score -1):

(@"^((([0-9]+)(.([0-9]+))?)(\,(([0-9]+)(.([0-9]+))?))*)$")

This works for comma separated whole number or comma separated decimal numbers.

Example:
Happy scenarios:
case 1) 9,10
case 2) 10.1,11,12,15,15.2
case 3) 9.8
case 4) 9

Sad scenarios:
case 1) 2..7
case 2) 2,,7
case 3) 2.
case 4) 7,
case 5) ,
case 6) .
case 7) .2
case 8) ,2

Comment: The OP states they want white space between numbers, not commas.