# how to check valid decimal point number with Regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

how can i check number is valid with below string.

last 2 digit may content decimal value or may not.

below are the code which i have already tried with `preg_match` but couldn't get any success

```
$newPrice = "2,264.00"; or //  $newPrice = "264.00"; 

 if (!preg_match('/^[+-][0-9]+(\,[0-9]+)?%?$/', $newPrice))
{                
    echo "not valid";
 }else{                    
       echo "valid";
}
exit();
```

above both price is correct as per allowed format.

Comment: you can refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565994/regex-to-match-comma-separated-numbers-with-optional-decimal-part

Comment: `/(?<=\s|^)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d\d)?|\.\d\d)(?=\s|$)/` is more than sufficient :) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex has 3 parts;

```
[0-9]{1,3}     1-3 digits
(,[0-9]{3})*   An optional repeated part of a comma + 3 digits
(\.[0-9]{2})?  An optional part of a decimal dot and 2 digits
```

This can be written as;

```
/^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{2})?$/
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
^[+-]?[\d\,]+\.?\d+?
```

this will match values like :

```
222,222,264.00
+2,424,24.34
-264
264.00
```

[**demo**](http://regex101.com/r/qZ7xJ4)

Comment: this finds only ONE number

Comment: @Sliq I think you can just remove the `^` from the beginning of the regex and it will work for more than one number also

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
[0-9,]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qFVcrVk9J0W4a19a)

Comment: what is values is like `222,222,264.00` ?