# Javascript regex integer number with decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex for the following condition:

**Allow to enter up to 1 decimal place and if I start with integer 0; the next has to be decimal otherwise any other number entered will remove the 0(integer)**

The regex that I have provided is `/(^$)|(^[0-9]+(\.([0-9]{1})?)?$)/` it accepts 1 decimal place but I am unable to achieve the remaining part.

### Edit 1

passed numbers -->
1.3

4.5

0.4

Failed numbers ---->

004

If number starts with 0, next character must be a decimal only
Eg,

0.5 is a pass

005 is a failed

Comment: This is not clear, please provide the code you are using the regex in and a couple of sample inputs/expected outputs.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22397004/17300) is PHP, not Javascript, and for two decimals, but the regex principles are the same.

Comment: agree with Wiktor, this question _really_ needs more details. You say "upto 1 decimal place" — do you mean only one digit should be allowed after the (optional) decimal place, e.g. should `3.1416` be rejected? Is a bare decimal with nothing after it allowed, e.g. is `17.` ok? Is the only problem "the remaining part"? That is to say, is stripping off the leading zeros the only issue you have? Stripping off the leading `000` can be a separate concern from matching with the regex. `regex.test(string)` and `string.match(regex)` are different for different purposes, which are you using?

Comment: @StephenP - i have updated the question properly, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

^([1-9]+\d*.?\d?)|^(0.\d)

If not, see comments and try to better exemplify

Comment: i have updated the question properly, please have a look

Comment: No details and very confusing your question. You speak for example of "removing" the first digit if it starts at 0 and the next is a number other than a decimal, but young man, you just say a regular expression and nothing else, a regular expression looks for patterns. As your question has no information and is only confused, what I can deduce is that the user will type values ​​in an input and you needed to put conditions for the values ​​entered (functions, methods, algorithms, logic, ...).

My regular expression will * read * only decimal values ​​of type, 0.3, 2.4, 321.4, 0.4

Comment: Where are you going to use this regular expression? What is your algorithm about? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^([0]{1}(\.[0-9]+))$|^([1-9]{1}|[1-9][0-9]+)$
```

**ADJUSTED REGEX:**
I have now adjusted the regex as required: all numbers that start with 0 MUST follow a comma, e.g. 0.2 or 0.0002 is accepted. 02 or 00002 is NOT accepted

Comment: Your regex rejects decimals > 9 — OPs regex accepts them, for example  `98.6`. OP says _"upto 1 decimal place"_ which usually means 1 significant digit _after_ the decimal place, but the question is unclear.

Comment: yes the question isn‘t clear... I have now changed the answer, but do not know if that is where you are looking for because the question is not clear

Comment: i have updated the question properly, please have a look

Comment: @akash89 I have edited the post... look whether it fits now ...

Answer (score 0):

OK, you want find integer number not start with 0, and find decimal?
Your code is: `/(^$)|(^[0-9]+(\.([0-9]{1})?)?$)/`

Case 1: integer `[1-9]\d*`

Case 2: decimal

```
//match 5.0
patt = \d+\.\d+

//Match 5.1xxxx, 5.2xxx, etc.
patt = \d+\.[1-9]\d*

//match 5.0xxx
patt = \d+\.0\d+

//combine all of them
patt = ([1-9]\d*|\d+\.[1-9]\d*|\d+\.0\d+)

//Final
patt = /(^$)|(([1-9]\d*|\d+\.[1-9]\d*|\d+\.0\d+)?$)/
```

I will explain some pattern above:

```
\d == [0-9]     //match 1 character between 0 and 9
\d* == \d{0,}   //match 0 or more character
\d+ == \d{1,}   //match at least one character
```