# Regex for MoneyFormat w/ (,) and (.) Optionals

Tags: regex

Hy guys i need to implement a money format data validation, i need this regex only accept the following formats:
Note: Only accept two or one positions for decimal before dot, the commas are optional every 3 digits

```
1
1.0
1.00
100.00
1,000.00
1000.00
111,000.00
111000.00
999,999,999.00
```

Assuming the Dot and commas are optionals.

Wrong Formats:

```
,1.00
1.
1,,00.00
1.000
etc
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx to match comma separated numbers with optional decimal part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565994/regex-to-match-comma-separated-numbers-with-optional-decimal-part)

Comment: This is not a duplicate since the requirements differ.

Comment: There are two critical pieces of information missing from this question. You need to tell us 1) **what language / platform you're using** as each regex engine has its own quirks, and 2) **what have you tried** before you came here and why your attempt didn't work.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg This Regex has other requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one can help:

`^\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d|\.\d\d)?$`

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/tM9lX5/2)