# regexpr and only matching prices and not other digits

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to come up with code that will extract only the price from a line of text.

Motivated by [RegEx for Prices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547574/regex-for-prices), I came up with the following command:

```
gregexpr('\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})', '23434 34.232 asdf 3.12  ')

[[1]]
[1]  7 19
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 5 4
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

However, in my case, I would only like `3.12` to match and not `34.232`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to extract the value, then its better/straightforward to use `sub` than `gregexpr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
'\\d+\\.\\d{1,2}(?!\\d)'
```

Comment: Thanks, works for me when used with `perl = T` argument.  Above also works with `gregexpr`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\\d+\\.\\d{1,2}(?!\\d)
```

I'm not 100% sure that negative lookahead is supported in `r`, so here is an alternative:

```
\\d+\\.\\d{1,2}(?:[^\\d]|$)
```

Comment: Things like negative lookaheads are supported in R if you use the `perl=TRUE` argument.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to wrap `\\d+\\.\\d{1,2}` in parenthesis if you wanted to be able to capture it?

Comment: @Michael Not if it's the entire match.

Comment: Hi, I just tried the alternative, and it's matching `34.232`, not `3.12`.

Comment: @andrewj Michael was correct about capturing, since the final digit will also be captured by the whole match

Answer (score -2):

one or more digits followed by a point, followed by 1 or 2 digits, followed by white space or end of string

```
\\d+\\.\\d{1,2}(\w|$)
```

Edit: as per comments, R uses double-escape

Comment: Won't work. You didn't escape the period. You're also either capturing words after the end of the price or assuming that the price is at the end of the string, both of which the OP probably doesn't want. .

Comment: Right you are about the escaping of period. accidentally un-escaped it... wrapping the entire thing in parenthesis and putting it as part of a bigger statement will allow Marius to just select the matching token

Comment: Note the `r` tag.  That's why all the other answers have double escapes:  \\ .

Comment: @Matthew this is the difficulty in tagging regex within R.  regex in a way is its own thing and those unfamiliar with R assume regex is regex.  I'm often hesitant about using the regex tag in R (on SO) for this reason.

Comment: Noted, thanks for alerting me to paying more attention to Tag descriptions :)