# shell regex: Extract prices

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed, grep

Given the following list of prices, I am trying to figure out how to normalize/extract only the digits.

```
INPUT          DESIRED_OUTPUT

CA$1399.00     1399.00
&#36;1399.11   1399.11
$1,399.22<     1399.22
Z$1 399.33     1399.33
$1399.44#      1399.44
C$ 1399.55     1399.55
1,399.66       1399.66
1399.77        1399.77
,1399.88       1399.88
25 1399.88     1399.88
399.99          399.99
88.88 99.99      99.99 (if >2 matches on one line, only the last one matters)
.1399.88         DO NOT MATCH (not a price; too many ".")
666.000          DO NOT MATCH (not a price: too many 0's)
```

I suppose it is a good idea to begin is with what they all have in common:

- Prices always contain `.NN`, but never contain `.NNN`

Upon further inspection, other rules become apparent:

- `.NN` must be preceded by one or more `digits`.
- `NNN.NN` can be preceded by either `,`,  , or a simple `digit`, but nothing else.
- Anything following `.NN` and preceding `*N.NN` marks the end of the match.
- Finally, the regex needs to consider commas in things like `1,399.66` (`1399.66`) to determine whether it is a price, but then strip them. `1, 399.66`, for instance does not equal `1399.66`: it should be `399.66`.

I am looking at `sed`, `grep`, and `awk` for a portable and efficient solution. How should I go about approaching this problem?

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547574/regex-for-prices?rq=1), but I have no idea how to try the following regex with `sed`:

```
^\d+(,\d{1,2})?$
```

EDIT: Yes, my input format is can be a little weird, because it is the result of the concatenation of scraped pages.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138937 recommending `grep -o`. Your inputs are in a really awkward format - `Z$1 399.33` should match the number before the space but `25 1399.88` should not match the number before the space? Why - by what rule can that distinction be encoded? What are the rest of the program and data like - can you do a cleanup run or multiple runs through?

Comment: A space/comma in position `4`, `8`, `12`, etc (RTL). is acceptable, so `1 399.88`, `1 333 399.88`, and `1 133 333 399.88` are OK. Matching `Z$1 399.33` should not be a big deal; the number ends as soon as $ appears (reading RTL, again).

Comment: Tricky case: `.1399.98` must not be matched, while `1 399.98` corresponds to `1399.98`. But then what about `.1 399.98`. Is the space then significant such that this is matched and the price is `399.98`?  I think the requirement should be that the case is resolved by extracting `.1` as a token, where the trailing space terminates the fraction. The next numeric token is `399.98`: good price.

Comment: What strictly portable Unix tools are you using to scrape this data?

Comment: Good point. Human common sense tells us that `.1 399.98` standing on its own is `1399.98`, but in other contexts, such a permissive rule could lead to false positives, which is why I rejected `.1399.88` in the first place. I'm not sure how to solve this, but `.1 399.98` is rather unlikely anyway. @Kaz curl. I use curl.

Comment: What I'm getting from this is that the easiest approach is 1. reverse the lines. 2. look for nn.nnn,nnn,...,nn looking for commas or spaces. e.g. `\d\d\.((\d){3}(, ))+\d+` ? It seems much easier to run it backwards.

Comment: "Human common sense" tells us that your problem isn't strictly well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following shell script:

```
#/bin/sh
grep -v '\.\d\+\.' | # get rid of lines with multiple dots within the same number
grep -v '\.\d\d\d\+' | # get rid of lines with more than 2 digits after .
sed -e 's/\(.*\.[0-9][0-9]\).*$/\1/' | # remove anything after last .NN
sed -e 's/^.* \([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\./\1./' | # "* NNNN." => "NNNN."
sed -e 's/^.* \([0-9][0-9]\)\./\1./' | # "* NN." => "NN."
sed -e 's/^.* \([0-9]\)\./\1./' | # "* N." => "N."
sed -e 's/^\(.*\)[ ,]\(\([0-9]\)\{3,\}\)\./\1\2./g' | # "*,NNN." or "* NNN." => "*NNN."
sed -e 's/^\(.*\)[ ,]\(\([0-9]\)\{6,\}\)\./\1\2./g' | # "*,NNNNNN." or "* NNNNNN." => "*NNNNNN."
sed -e 's/^\(.*\)[ ,]\(\([0-9]\)\{9,\}\)\./\1\2./g' | # "*,NNNNNNNNN." or "* NNNNNNNNN." => "*NNNNNNNNN."
grep -o '\d\+\.\d\d' # print only the price
```

In case of numbers that are separated by space or `,` in groups of 3 digits, this solution works up to 9 digits before the `.`. If you need to extract bigger prices, just add more lines, increasing the number in the regex by 3. ;-)

Put it in a file called `extract_prices`, make it executable (`chmod +x extract_prices`) and run it: `./extract_prices < my_list.txt`

Tested on OS X using the following input:

```
CA$1399.00
&#36;1399.11
$1,399.22<
Z$1 399.33
Z$12 777 666.34   # <-- additonal monster price
$1399.44#
C$ 1399.55
1,399.66
1399.77
,1399.88
25 1399.88
399.99
88.88 99.99
.1399.88
666.000
```

Which generates the following output:

```
1399.00
1399.11
1399.22
1399.33
12777666.34
1399.44
1399.55
1399.66
1399.77
1399.88
1399.88
399.99
99.99
```

Comment: Instead of removing trailing `#` and `<` explicitly, couldn't you simply strip anything that follows the last instance of exactly two numbers preceded by a dot (`.NN`)?

Comment: True. That part isn't that hard.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, BTW :)

Comment: Okay, got a solution! Lol. Hacky, but it works. And thanks! Finally trying to get some reputation... lol

Comment: How come `echo "$1,399.22" | extract_prices` produces an incorrect `399.22` , while `echo '$1,399.22' | extract_prices` produces a correct `1399.22`?

Comment: @octosquidopus that's because the shell performs variable expansion in double quoted strings. $1 would be the first argument given to a script or function. in this case, no argument given, so I guess it'll transform the string into `",399.22"` before `extract_prices` even reads it.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with **awk** that splits on all characters that are not numbers or decimal point and prints the last field that matches a price.  The leading **sed** script handles the exception case #3 where we have a space instead of a comma marking the thousands spot.

```
sed -e 's/  / x /g; :a; s/\(\$[1-9][0-9]*\) /\1/; ta' | awk -F '[^0-9.]' -v p='[0-9]+\\.[0-9][0-9]' '$0 ~ p { gsub(/,/, ""); for (i=NF; i>0; i--) if ($i ~ "^" p "$") { print $i; next } }'
```

Notes:

1) The **sed** script uses a test to iterate; therefore, it can handle millions, billions, etc.
2) The **sed** script also handles the multiple space condition such that $1[ ][ ]1000.00 does not become $11000.00 in the end.
3) Commas are simply stripped/ignored... if there is an issue with comma separation of numbers, the issue can be resolved by getting rid of the gsub in the **awk** script and fixing the filter in the leading **sed** script

Here is a more complicated version that builds on the idea in note #3 to make commas and spaces part of the number only if the space or comma is at a thousands separator.

```
sed -e ':a; s/\(\$[1-9][0-9]*\) \([0-9][0-9][0-9][ .]\)/\1\2/; ta; :b; s/\([1-9][0-9]*\),\([0-9][0-9][0-9][,.]\)/\1\2/; tb;' | awk -F '[^0-9.]' -v p='[0-9]+\\.[0-9][0-9]' '$0 ~ p { for (i=NF; i>0; i--) if ($i ~ "^" p "$") { print $i; next } }'
```

If chance of success is high on each line, then getting rid of "p" would make for a more efficient script.

```
sed -e ':a; s/\(\$[1-9][0-9]*\) \([0-9][0-9][0-9][ .]\)/\1\2/; ta; :b; s/\([1-9][0-9]*\),\([0-9][0-9][0-9][,.]\)/\1\2/; tb;' | awk -F '[^0-9.]' '{ for (i=NF; i>0; i--) if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]$/) { print $i; next } }'
```

Finally, for safety, we can check in the **sed** filter to make sure we have a valid space or comma delimited number before we do either substitution.

```
sed -e ':a; /\$[1-9][0-9]\?[0-9]\?\( [0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\+\.[0-9][0-9]/ s/\(\$[1-9][0-9]*\) \([0-9][0-9][0-9][ .]\)/\1\2/; ta; :b; /[1-9][0-9]\?[0-9]\?\(,[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\+\.[0-9][0-9]/ s/\([1-9][0-9]*\),\([0-9][0-9][0-9][,.]\)/\1\2/; tb;' | awk -F '[^0-9.]' '{ for (i=NF; i>0; i--) if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]$/) { print $i; next } }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -r '/\n/!s/([^0-9]*\b(([0-9])[ ,]([0-9]{3})|([0-9]+))(\.[0-9]{2})\b)+/\n\3\4\5\6\n/;/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}\b/P;D' file
```

This works with the data provided but some of the specification is a bit sketchy.